# "Не удается преобразовать из List<MyType> в List<T>" в конструкторе базового класса

Tags: c#, generics, конструктор

Есть базовый класс, конструктор которого принимает `List<T>`:

```
public class EditListElementsVM<T> where T : class, INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public EditListElementsVM(List<T>elementsList)  =
    {
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

И есть наследующий класс вызывающий конструктор родителя:

```
public class DocumentVM : EditListElementsVM
{   
    // Ошибка: Не удается преобразовать List<Document> в List<T>
    public DocumentVM(List<Document> elementsList) : base(elementsList)
    {
          //...
    }
    //...
}
```

Я наверное не очень разбираюсь в дженериках, но разве `List<Document>` не должен подходить под сигнатуру `List<T>`?

Пробовал другую сигнатуру конструктора наследника, так тоже не работает:

```
public class DocumentVM : EditListElementsVM
{
    public DocumentVM(List<Document> elementsList) : base<Document>()
    {

    }
}
```

p.s. исправил несогласованность по доступности родителя и наследника

Comment: `: EditListElementsVM` -> `: EditListElementsVM<Document>`. Также обратите внимание на `where T : class, INotifyPropertyChanged` - этим вы говорите "Т должен быть классом и реализовать INPC", вы уверены, что это поведение вам нужно? Если нужно чтоб `EditListElementsVM` реализовал INPC, то интерфейс перед `where` пишите (`EditListElementsVM<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged where T : class`).

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно. Пожалуйста оформите ответ, если хотите, чтобы я его принял.

Comment: Написание ответа, пожалуй, предоставлю вам)

Answer (score 1):

Благодаря @EvgeniyZ вопрос был решен следующим образом: необходимо указать дженерик сигнатуру родительского класса, т.е

```
public class DocumentVM : EditListElementsVM<Document>
{   }
```